# Ionic 3 sending notifications based on local event even if app is closed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

Using the native-sensors plugin i have created a method which will notify the user when the temperature and humidity exceed a certain limit. Using the native-background mode method I was able to send these notifications when the app is in the background. But the notifications dont arrive if I kill the app.

Is there someway to use local notifications to get my needed functionality? or can I use push notifications somehow achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately no;( push notifications can be listened to by the device when your app is not loaded, but it cant sort of produce anything locally while your app is not loaded. Its like one direction communication.